# Unable to use the the mui/x-chart after install

Tags: reactjs, mui-x, mui-x-charts

Steps to reproduce:

1. npm install @mui/x-charts
2. import { BarChart } from '@mui/x-charts/BarChart';

The install with "npm install @mui/x-charts" has no problem.
But when I try to use [BarChart]
`import { BarChart } from '@mui/x-charts/BarChart';`
it gets the error:

```
(6:5) start value has mixed support, consider using flex-start instead
Failed to compile.                                                           
                                                                             
./node_modules/@react-spring/core/dist/react-spring_core.legacy-esm.js 106:11
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (106:11)                               
File was processed with these loaders:                                       
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js                                  
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.     
| }                                                                          
| function detachRefs(ctrl, ref) {                                           
>   ctrl.ref?.delete(ctrl);                                                  
|   ref?.delete(ctrl);                                                       
| }
```

My package.json looks like:

```
{
  "name": "application",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@date-io/date-fns": "^1.3.13",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.4.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.3.0",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.56",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.10.9",
    "@mui/x-charts": "^6.19.5",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "immutability-helper": "^3.1.1",
    "material-ui-dropzone": "^3.5.0",
    "print-js": "^1.2.0",
    "react": "^17.0.0",
    "react-circular-progressbar": "^2.0.3",
    "react-dnd": "^11.1.3",
    "react-dnd-html5-backend": "^11.1.3",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.0",
    "react-pdf": "^5.0.0",
    "react-qr-code": "^2.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-script-tag": "^1.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.3",
    "react-to-print": "^2.14.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "make-pretty-jsx": "prettier --write \"**/*.{css,js,json,jsx,md}\" \"!package*.json\" \"!build/**/*\" \"!dist/**/*\"",
    "make-pretty-css": "prettier-stylelint --write \"**/*.css\" \"!package*.json\"",
    "make-everything-pretty": "npm run make-pretty-jsx",
    "lint-everything": "lerna run --concurrency 1 --stream lint:quiet",
    "lint-everything:fix": "lerna run --concurrency 1 --stream lint:fix",
    "precommit": "lint-staged"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "linters": {
      "*.{js,jsx}": [
        "prettier --write",
        "eslint --quiet",
        "git add"
      ],
      "*.{json,md}": [
        "prettier --write",
        "git add"
      ],
      "*.css": [
        "prettier-stylelint --write",
        "stylelint",
        "git add"
      ]
    },
    "ignore": [
      "**/flow-typed/**/*",
      "**/build/**/*",
      "package*.json",
      "README.md"
    ]
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lerna run --concurrency 1 --stream precommit"
    }
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-constant-elements": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.12.1",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.9.9",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.56",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "^3.2.10",
    "@mui/material": "^5.9.0",
    "@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin": "^0.4.3",
    "@react-pdf/renderer": "^1.6.11",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-hoist-facc": "^0.2.3",
    "babel-plugin-minify-constant-folding": "^0.5.0",
    "babel-plugin-react-css-modules": "^5.2.6",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^10.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "bson-objectid": "^1.3.1",
    "copy-to-clipboard": "^3.3.1",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.2",
    "css-loader": "^5.0.1",
    "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.6.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.15.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.4",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.21.5",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-unicorn": "^23.0.0",
    "husky": "^4.2.5",
    "lerna": "^3.22.1",
    "lint-staged": "^10.2.2",
    "material-ui": "^0.20.2",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.4",
    "password-generator": "^2.3.2",
    "postcss": "^8.1.7",
    "postcss-load": "^0.1.6",
    "postcss-loader": "^4.0.4",
    "postcss-modules-values": "^4.0.0",
    "prettier": "^2.0.5",
    "prettier-stylelint": "^0.4.2",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react-datepicker": "^3.2.2",
    "react-material-ui-datatable": "^2.0.0-alpha.30",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "react-router": "^5.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-devtools": "^3.5.0",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
    "reselect": "^4.0.0",
    "sockjs-client": "^1.4.0",
    "stompjs": "^2.3.3",
    "stylelint": "^13.7.2",
    "stylelint-config-css-modules": "^2.2.0",
    "stylelint-config-prettier": "^8.0.2",
    "stylelint-prettier": "^1.1.2",
    "uuid": "^7.0.3"
  }
}
```

According to the documentation, this one should work.

Does any one know what cause this issue and how to resolve it?

Thank you so much!